# wp7 Display string in webbrowser or otherway?

Tags: string, windows-phone-7, browser

```
string a="hi <p> how </p> are <Br> you?</Br>";
```

How can avoid this tags `<p> </p><Br> </Br>`.

In output coming like that : Hi how are you?

If anyone know the answer help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`NavigateToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) to render custom HTML in a WebBrowser control:

```
string html = "<html><body>hi <p> how </p> are <br /> you?</body></html>";

webBrowser.NavigateToString(html);
```